# Calculating the average traverse time for a graph in millisecond gives an inconceivable output?

Tags: java, time, double, milliseconds

I'm making a performance test about search in graphs (between an adjacency list and adjacency matrix) to calculate average traverse time for whole graph in ms.

However, the output gives a number that I havent seen before. Here is the simple algorithm of test.

```
   double startTime;
   double endTime;
   double processTime;

   double totalTime = 0;
   double averageTime = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {


        startTime = System.nanoTime();

        search.DFS(5);

        endTime = System.nanoTime();

        processTime = (endTime - startTime)/1000000;

        totalTime = totalTime + processTime;
    }

    averageTime = totalTime/100000;

    System.out.println("PROCESS TIME in AdjacencyMatrix = " + averageTime + " ms");
```

and the output looks like ;

```
PROCESS TIME in AdjacencyMatrix = 1.4765902999997995E-4 ms
```

When I traverse just one time the output gives convenient data like `0.032344 ms`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you use double you still can get precision errors. Basically a floating point number is always a sum of numbers to the power of ten. With that means not all number can be saved precisely. I'm guessing that's where your problem lies.

As a  solution: Use `long` for your variables which is the return type of `System.nanoTime()`. The number returned by this is always a whole number.

Comment: @Goacat has a good point. Still the second part of my answer is important. You should change your code even if Goacat's answer is the right solution.

Comment: Then your program seems to be very fast acctually. To see some results work with nanoseconds instead of miliseconds, at least in the loop. If one iteration is very fast `processTime` will always be rounded to 0 and `totalTime` also adds up to 0. If you use nanoseconds for those it wont be 0 and when it's rounded in the end you have less precision loss. But using double defenitly makes no sense.

Comment: Thats very clear answer. Now i gave up to convert ns into ms and using ns as unit for time testing and it gives precise results :). well thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 3):

The number is simply written as a floating point number.

1.4765902999997995E-4 = 0.000147659...

So because it's a very small number, the output is in float format to be easier to read.

EDIT: To clarify about floating point number. It's just a way to write numbers that is usually referred to as "scientific notation". This is just a different and convenient way to write very large or very small numbers. In school you might've run into something like:

> 3,000,000 = 3 * 10^6 = 3E6
>
> 1,456,000,000,000 = 1.456 * 10^12 = 1.456E12

So the "E" simply means *10^. If the numbers are small, you use negative numbers after the E, like this:

> 0,04653 = 4.653 * 10^-2 = 4.653E-2
>
> 0,00000134 = 1.34 * 10^-6 = 1.34E-6
>
> 0.000000000000000018 = 1.8 * 10^-17 = 1.8E-17

If you want more examples, you can the box in the top right corner of this [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation)

Comment: i dont know what E character refers to ?. Could you explain ?. And also i will consider not take more than 5 or 6 digits so i guess i have to get rid off them. :)

Comment: I edited the post to explain some more about floating point numbers! =)